# Is it possible to login into different communities(multiple domains) from one apex controller?

Tags: visualforce, single-sign-on, community, session, mydomain

Is it possible to login into different communities(multiple domains) from one controller? Is it possible to use Site.login() for this or there are different ways to do this?

Issue is that SSO doesnt work with multiple domains.

Any help will be appreciated,
Thank you!